# ActiveRecord where included record's attribute is compared to original record's attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

If I have models like AModel, BModel, and CModel, I want to do an ActiveRecord query something like

```
AModel.includes(:b_model).where.not('b_model.c_model_id = ?', AModel.c_model.id)
```

The only trouble that I'm having with that query is that last part

```
AModel.c_model_id
```

which is trying to refer to the current AModel record. Is it possible to refer back to AModel's c_model_id attribute using that query?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to refer back to AModel's c_model_id attribute using that query?

No, this isn't possible. This is a smell of circular referencing database models, which should be avoided. Re-evaluate your database schema, or post a more specific use case to work through the problem with a better data structure.